# Tooltip in a overflow: scroll; element

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div that is set to overflow scroll, and I want to display tool-tips within them, the tool-tips are "leaking" out of the container, therefore it gets hidden. I saw other questions on StackOverflow about this problem and basically  they all remove the `position: relative;` of the containing element, but I need the `position: relative;` in order the tool-tips should render in the correct place.
 Having this problem for a while, help is greatly appreciated! 

 [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyfoa90L/) here

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Any link or code please,

Comment: Here is a JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eyfoa90L/

Answer (score 0):

Oke thanks for the update of your question, check out the snipper below,

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

span.tip {
  display: none;
}

.child:hover > span.tip {
  display: block;
}

.tip {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
  content: attr(data-tipsy);
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  test tooltip
    <span class="tip" data-tipsy="Simple Tipsy">Test Tipsy</span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, maecenas.
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  test tooltip
    <span class="tip" data-tipsy="Simple Tipsy">Test Tipsy</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ofcourse you have to style it like you want.

Comment: The problem with this is that this tooltip is positioned relative and therefore will take up place in the flow of the page, I need a position absolute solution

Comment: Check the snippet again, is this what you need?

Comment: OP has an `overflow: scroll`

Comment: Now you removed the overflow: scroll property and that is nesecery for my code, here is a updated JSFiddle and this is what I need https://jsfiddle.net/0qfzxbvk/ thanks for your work!

Comment: I've add it again, hopefully i helped you on this ;-), if so please vote for me :). Regards!

Comment: Now the tooltip get hidden again :-) https://jsfiddle.net/hdxL66w3/  I think now you nailed my problem, its very frustrating

Comment: I think I lost my way in this case ;-). Is it fixed now or is there something else what i can do?

Comment: Its not fixed and I think that is just not possible in CSS, Ill have to use a JS tooltip, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually require the `overflow:scroll` tag so that you don't have scrollbars?

If so I got around this by just removing the `overflow` altogether - but not sure if this is what you need. Its the only way I could do it by keeping the `position:relative`

See amended fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/eyfoa90L/3/

Comment: I do need the overflow property I need a solution that the parent has a overflow scroll and the tooltip has a position absolute  https://jsfiddle.net/0qfzxbvk/

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot solve this problem in CSS, because the :hover property of css always needs a child element of the "hover" element to use its properties on it.
If you would want to solve this problem you would need to put the tooltip outside of any parent element that gets hovered over.

I think Javascript and addEventListener('onmouseover',function) is your best bet here.